# Compare text with table field name

Tags: ms-access-2010

Is possible to compare a text with the name of a field in a table ?

Ex.: I have a table with fields (p300, p600, P1200, P1800, etc.), these fields are of type True or False, and my application will come a parameter which will be a text (p300, p600, P1200, P1800 etc.) then had to return only the values ​​where the field is true, but first needed to compare what field I will check.

Say my parameter is p600, would then have to verify the p600 column, however as I have several speakers wondered if he had somehow first find the columnar to then check if the value of that column is true or false.

I thought of using somethig like this, UtilizaVariavelGlobal ( ' Plano' ) is my variable that has the same name as the table field .

```
Select * from Table Where Table.UtilizaVariavelGlobal ( ' Plano' ) = True
```

Instead of p600 would like to use a variable that has the same name of the field ?
Thank you !

[DB_Test](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1CBDD42318B88DB7!8611&authkey=!ALSeuyl81SNWero&ithint=file%2Czip)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can concatenate a string:

```
FieldName = "P600"

SQL = "Select * From YourTable Where [" & FieldName & "] = True"
```

or with a function:

```
SQL = "Select * From YourTable Where [" & UtilizaVariavelGlobal("Plano") & "] = True"
```

With a recordset it is easy too:

```
Criteria = FieldName & " = True"
rst.FindFirst Criteria
```

Even DLookup:

```
FoundId = DLookup("ID", "YourTable", "" & FieldName & " = True")
```

Comment: It did not work that way ,[" & FieldName & "] = True" , 
the name of the field will come from variable UtilizaVariavelGlobal ( ' Plano' ). @Gustav https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1CBDD42318B88DB7!8611&authkey=!ALSeuyl81SNWero&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Well, then just replace with your function. See edit.

Comment: You will have to build the SQL string, then assign it to the SQL property of the query - or run it from VBA opening a recordset.